# Error running Sample JavaFX Maven in Netbeans 11 due to Unrecognized option: --module-path

Tags: java, maven, javafx, netbeans-11, module-path

I have tried to create a new JavaFX project following this tutorial.
https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx
I also tried the sample project.

> Finally, note that you can get a similar built-in sample from NetBeans -> File -> New Project... -> Samples -> OpenJFX

In both instances I get the same error message.

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
    Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
    Unrecognized option: --module-path
    Command execution failed.
    org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:491)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:453)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:97)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:491)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:453)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:97)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BUILD FAILURE
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total time: 6.191 s
    Finished at: 2019-08-30T09:34:42-03:00
    Final Memory: 23M/80M
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:run (default-cli) on project HelloFXMLWithMaven: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:run (default-cli) on project HelloFXMLWithMaven: Error
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:114)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:108)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:491)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:453)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:97)
        ... 22 more


    For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: I always check the Java -version when I get errors like these. Sometimes windows can reset the Java -version.

Comment: You are running with Java 1.8.  See the NetBeans section https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans on how to edit its conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while ago and took me some time to solve it...

Assuming:

- Java 11
- JavaFX 12
- groupId: com.app
- artifactId: main
- mainClass: com.app.main.MainApp

Your pom file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>App ABC</name>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <name>Company XYZ</name>
    </organization>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.app.main.MainApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And your nbactions.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
    <action>
        <actionName>run</actionName>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>package</goal>
            <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <runfx.args>-jar "${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"</runfx.args>               
        </properties>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>debug</actionName>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>package</goal>
            <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <runfx.args>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -Dglass.disableGrab=true -jar "${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"</runfx.args>
            <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>                
        </properties>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>CUSTOM-Build maven</actionName>
        <displayName>Build maven</displayName>
        <preAction>build-with-dependencies</preAction>
        <goals>
            <goal>mvn</goal>
            <goal>-X</goal>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>install</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <runfx.args>-jar "${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"</runfx.args>            
        </properties>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>run.single.main</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>*</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>process-classes</goal>
            <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <exec.args>-classpath %classpath ${packageClassName}</exec.args>
            <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
            <exec.classpathScope>${classPathScope}</exec.classpathScope>
        </properties>
    </action>        
</actions>
```

Finally, your nb-configuration.xml file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-shared-configuration>
    <!--
This file contains additional configuration written by modules in the NetBeans IDE.
The configuration is intended to be shared among all the users of project and
therefore it is assumed to be part of version control checkout.
Without this configuration present, some functionality in the IDE may be limited or fail altogether.
-->
    <properties xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/maven-properties-data/1">
        <!--
Properties that influence various parts of the IDE, especially code formatting and the like. 
You can copy and paste the single properties, into the pom.xml file and the IDE will pick them up.
That way multiple projects can share the same settings (useful for formatting rules for example).
Any value defined here will override the pom.xml file value but is only applicable to the current project.
-->
        <netbeans.compile.on.save>none</netbeans.compile.on.save>
    </properties>
</project-shared-configuration>
```